# CoreFoundation references and AddressBook programming

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, core-foundation

If want to check if a person record has email addresses. So:

```
ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

If the record has no email addresses, do I get a NULL value in `emailMultiValue`, or some other special `CFTypeRef` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get NULL value cause of `kABPersonEmailProperty` record returns multi value type.
Actually it returns valid object with empty list of values:
`NSLog(@"%@", emailMultiValue)` -> `ABMultiValueRef 0x156bbb00 with 0 value(s)`